# phpunit command gives permission denied error on laravel project

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-5, laravel-testing

When i try to execute

`vendor/bin/phpunit`

i get error 
`-bash: vendor/bin/phpunit: Permission denied`

on laravel 5.2 project. I tried deleting entire vendor folder and re installing with `composer install` but the error occurs same. is there any solution for this matter?

thanks.

Comment: `chmod +x vendor/bin/phpunit`? (makes it executable)

Comment: tried this but not working mate

Answer (score 2):

I tried `php vendor/bin/phpunit` and it works like a charm. and i set up phpunit on phpStorm. it works fine too

Comment: so I changed my alias to "php ./vendor/bin/phpunit"